# MVC3 - How to correctly inject dependencies with MVC3 and Ninject?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, ninject-2

I am attempting to redesign an existing application using dependency injection with Ninject in  MVC3.  Here is a portion of the legacy behavior I'm having difficulty with (and yes I know its bad, that's why I'm trying to refactor it):

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

    MyUserSession userSession = filterContext.HttpContext.Session[SESSIONKEY_USER] as MyUserSession;

    // if session  empty, rebuild user information
    if (userSession == null)
    {
        string userName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        userSession = new MyUserSession();

        using (ADSearcher ad = new ADSearcher(ldapPath, excludeOUString.Split(',')))
        {
            // get basic user information from Active Directory
            ADUserInfo aduser = MyActiveDirectorySearcher.GetUserRecord(userName);

            // ... set several properties queries from AD... 
            userSession.propertyXYZ = aduser.propXYZ
        }   

        // if user can proxy as another indivudual, set property
        using (EDMContainer db = new EDMContainer())
        {
            if (db.Proxies.Any(p => p.ProxyLogin == userSession.userLogin))
                userSession.CanProxy == true;
        }

        // save new user object to session
        filterContext.HttpContext.Session[SESSIONKEY_USER] = userSession;

        if(userSession.canProxy)
            filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("Proxy", "Home");

        return;
    }
}
```

So currently, the controller users several objects directly: Session, ActiveDirectorySearch, EF Database.  I understand it would be better to create a class that exposes a single method "GetUser" masking all the complexity but I'm struggling with how to inject the dependencies.

If I create a class SomeUserProvider, it will also need access to the Session to check for existing user information, and then ActiveDirectorySearcher and Database to rebuild the user properties if session was empty.

My confusion is over the fact that the controller itself will need access to ActiveDirectorySearcher in other action methods and then other classes will also use the same database.  Do I inject an IActiveDirSearchrer into the controller's constructor and then pass it down into the ISomeUserProvider?  What about IMyDatabase?  Is it also injected in controller constructor and passed down?

And last but not lease, ISessionWrapper?  I know session is controversial, but I need to track who the current user is and who they are proxied as during each request (GETs and POSTs).  So, does that get injected as well?

If the answer is yes to each of those, is it bad to have 3+ injected contstuctor parameters?

I realize my question may be vague, so please ask for clarification where needed.  I am open to any and all suggestions and recommendations.  My goal is to learn how to do it correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think your question is vague--good job :) No, it's not bad practice to inject multiple dependencies if you can't logically combine them at another level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not certain if this is exactly what you're looking for, but this should get you started down the path of refactoring your app for DI

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISessionWrapper _sessionWrapper;
    private readonly IActiveDirSearcher _adSearcher;
    private readonly IMyDatabase _database;

    public YourController(ISessionWrapper sessionWrapper,
        IActiveDirSearcher adSearcher, IMyDatabase database)
    {
        this._sessionWrapper = sessionWrapper;
        this._adSearcher = adSearcher;
        this._database = database;
    }

    // now all actions in this controller have a _sessionWrapper,
    // _adSearcher and _database
}
```

Then you have to bind your injections the Ninject way. Subclass your application from `NinjectHttpApplication` and override `OnApplicationStarted` and `CreateKernel`

```
public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
{
    // ...

    protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        base.OnApplicationStarted();

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<ISessionWrapper>().To<YourSessionWrapperImplementation>();
        kernel.Bind<IActiveDirSearcher>().To<YourADImplementation>();
        kernel.Bind<IMyDataBase>().To<YourEDMContainerIThink>();

        return kernel;
    }
}
```

The implementations of these appear to be described in your question. However, you mentioned other actions (*and other classes*) depend on these implementations. Good news--the bindings in `CreateKernel` will take care of any missing dependencies elsewhere in your app. e.g.

```
public class MyActiveDirImplementation : IActiveDirSearcher
{
    private readonly IMyDatabase _database;

    // injected automagically WOOHOO!
    public MyActiveDirImplementation(IMyDatabase database)
    {
        this._database = database;
    }

    public ADUserInfo GetUserRecord(string username)
    {
        return _database.GetSomeUserRecord(username);
    }
}
```

You could, of course, similarly implement your `ISessionWrapper` or `IMyDatabase`

Comment: Thanks for the example.  It was that last section that I was not grasping.